# .htaccess Require valid-user [except from localhost]

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to password protect a directory except from requests that come from localhost.
My .htaccess looks like this:

```
AuthName "Login"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /PATH/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from ::1
Satisfy Any


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

If I remove Allow and Satisfy statements the directory gets correctly protected. When I add the Allow (one or both) and Satisfy Any it generates a 500 error. The log says:

```
/PATH/.htaccess: allow not allowed here
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

If you you have access to server conf files, check for: `AllowOverride` See for what directives are allowed.

---

```
AllowOverride All
```

will allow all directives.

For more visit: [AllowOverride Directive <sup>Apache Docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

Comment: Doesn't work. According to Apache Docs AllowOverride is only applicable in <Directory> sections. Apache responds with "Syntax error on line 164 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
AllowOverride not allowed here". I want the setting in the .htaccess file and not the .conf file where the <directory> section is. Is it possible att all?